# Compute the inverse of a conditional quantile regression output

Tags: r, quantile-regression, importance-sampling

[Brunello et al (2009)](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1111/j.1468-0297.2008.02244.x) show that extended compulsory schooling leads to increased wages respectivly to the individual gender. Their empirical model first uses quantile regression to show the impact of compulsory schooling years (ycomp,
defined as the instrument variable z) on actual years of education (s). Afterwards they subtract those fitted values of the regression from s to get the ability of a person of a specific quantile.[2]

They claim that their model is exactly identified to do so.[3]

In the end they come up with a quantile regression aproach which is augmented by the control variate computed in [2]. But if I understand them correctly they compute the inverse of the $\tau$ - quantiles of distribution $a$ and $u$. [4]

If I got that right, could somenone help me to show how this is done? I suspect some kind of Monte-Carlo Method, e.g. importance sampling, but I'm unsure. A solution with R-code is appreciated but not necessary.

EDIT : Simplfying the question : How does one calculate $G_{a}^{-1}\left(\tau_{a}\right)$ and $G_{u}^{-1}\left(\tau_{u}\right)$?

> [2]:First, we estimate the conditional quantile functions of schooling $s$
> and compute the control variate $$
>  a\left(\tau_{a}\right)=s-\bar{Q}\left( \tau_{a} \mid X, z \right) $$

> [3]: Omitting subscripts for simplicity, the earnings-cum-education model
> presented above can be written in the format of an exactly identified
> triangular model, as in Chesher's approach $$ \begin{array}{c} \ln(w)=\beta s+s(\lambda a+\phi u)+\gamma_{w} X+a+u  &(6)\\ s=\gamma_{s} X+\pi
>  z+\xi a &(7)\end{array} $$

> [4]: Define $\tau_{a}=G_{a}\left(a_{\tau_{a}}\right) \text { and } \tau_{u}=G_{u}\left(u_{\tau_{u}}\right)$, where $a_{\tau_{a}}$ and
> $u_{\tau_{u}}$ are the $\tau-$ quantiles of the distributions of $a$
> and $u,$ respectively. Furthermore define $Q_{w}\left(\tau_{u} \mid s,
>  X, z\right)$ and $Q_{s}\left(\tau_{a} \mid X, z\right)$ as the
> conditional quantile functions corresponding to log wages and years of
> education. Ma and Koenker (2006) show that recursive conditioning
> yields the following model $$ \begin{array}{c} Q_{w}\left[\tau_{u}
>  \mid Q_s\left(\tau_{a} \mid X, z\right), X, z\right]=Q_s\left(\tau_{a}
>  \mid X, z\right) \Pi\left(\tau_{a}, \tau_{u}\right)+\gamma_{w}
>  X+G_{a}^{-1}\left(\tau_{a}\right)+G_{u}^{-1}\left(\tau_{u}\right)& (8) \\
>  Q_{s}\left(\tau_{a} \mid X, z\right)=\gamma_{s} X+\pi z+\xi
>  G_{a}^{-1}\left(\tau_{a}\right) & (9)\end{array} $$ Given the restrictions
> imposed by (6) and $(7),$ the key parameter of interest
> $\Pi\left(\tau_{a} \tau_{u}\right)$ is a matrix with the following
> structure $$ \begin{array}{c} \Pi\left(\tau_{a},
>  \tau_{u}\right)=\beta+\lambda G_{a}^{-1}\left(\tau_{a}\right)+\phi
>  G_{u}^{-1}\left(\tau_{u}\right) \quad \end{array} $$

EDIT : Added some clarification to the equation numbering, fixed the equation in the first qoute and added more information on variable ycomp/z. Fixed the main quantile regression equation (8) from subscript v to w (wages). Clarified the importance-sampling tag. Edited the subscripts of the distribution functions $\tau_a$ and $\tau_u$

Comment: Is the [tag:importance-sampling] tag relevant here?

Comment: That article takes some time to dig through, and the question is not easy to understand. Already the first line $\left(\tau_{a}\right)=s-\bar{Q}\left( \tau_{a} \mid X, z \right)$ is confusing to me without context. So the $\tau$ are quantiles but where does the subscript $a$ suddenly come from? Why is $\tau_a$ in both sides of the equation? What are the variables $X$ and $z$? .... Could you make the question more concise/simpler with a self-contained example?

Comment: @RichardHardy I thought that for the inverse of the quantile distribution one need some kind of Monte-Carlo integration. If I'm wrong here, I will delete the tag.

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus I'm sorry that I made a mistage in the first equation. Of course It should be $a(\tau_a)$ . Fixed that!

Comment: mistage should be mistake.

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus X are some controls and z ist the instrument defined as ycomp.

Comment: @mugdi, OK, makes sense. This was not obvious from the question as you do not mention this explicitly, though.

Comment: @SextusEmpericus True, hence I added an EDIT-Message to get a better overview what I fixed in the question.

Comment: @SextusEmpericus : The empirical model, where this question is about, is about two and a half pages long. I tried to break it down as best as I coudl but I think it is quite forward to dig through this part of the paper. Especially with my introduction to the topic.

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus Besides, if there is anything I can do to recieve an answear for this question by improving the latter. Feel free to name those things.

Comment: I am still looking into it, while I have not much time to read this article (which is very dense with information in my opinion). But I find the article interesting, yet also not easy (and maybe that is why I find it interesting). This is also not my field so I will have to read into it (all of the references are new to me).

Comment: For the sake of a question on cross validated, whenever you can distill the essence of the question from noisy/confusing field specific context, then it will always be better. I am not sure whether there is an economics stackechange, the question might do well there. Or otherwise the quants stackechange.

Comment: @SexitusEmpericus. I tried to distill the question to the estimation technique which was used in this paper. I focuses on summarizing the most important equations and explained what happend in my own words. Maybe this helps to clarify some things. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/488494/control-variate-estimator-for-quantile-regression

Btw. Thanks a lot for your patience. I never faced such an dense paper while using and estimation technique which is that complicated. I hope we can lift the mystery together :D

Comment: Besides, I discoverd that there is an economics stack exchange where I will post this question aswell and link the CV question of the control variate estimation technique. Maybe one can help there too!

Answer (score 0):

I think I found an answear to this on my own. Following Ma and Koenker one simply does the following :

For tau = 0.1 :

$G_{a}^{-1}\left(\tau_{a}\right)$ =

```
   ability_male_tau_01*qnorm(0.1,0,var(ability_male_t01))
```

$G_{u}^{-1}\left(\tau_{u}\right)$ =

```
   labour_luck_male_tau_01*qnorm(0.1,0,var(labour_luck_male_t01))
```

Maybe someone can verify this theoretically?